# Font not showing

Tags: html, css

I have attempted to change the colour of my font to black in header one which says, Michelle Lindemann's Magical Stories. However, I still cannot see it (it remains white). I am wondering if someone can assist me with the HTML and CSS coding please. I have attached a screen shot of the header and the HTML and CSS coding.

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 60%;
}

.carousel-caption h1 {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black !important;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  color: black !important;
}

.btn {
  font-weight: 500;
  border-width: medium;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="img/carleeandiheadertwo.png">
    <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
      <h1 class="display-2"></h1>Michelle Lindemann's Magical Stories</h1>
      <h3>Bringing your dreams to life!</h3>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">DISCOVER MORE</a>
    </div>
```

[screen shot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOTg6.jpg)

Comment: Hello, there is a typo in your code. Check your h1 tag mistakenly you have closed it without having any text inside it. Also, you added an extra closing tag. Here is the fix: `<h1 class="display-2">Michelle Lindemann's Magical Stories</h1>`

Comment: It appears to be working here. You may have some other code that is interfering that has not been shared.

Comment: Thanks so much, I appreciate your help. Michelle xx

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `</h1>` tag which caused the words not showing. Remove it and the h1 tag will show properly.

```
<h1 class="display-2"></h1>Michelle Lindemann's Magical Stories</h1>
```

```css
.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
}


.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 60%;
}


.carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black !important;
   

}

.carousel-caption h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    color: black !important;
}

.btn {
    font-weight: 500;
    border-width: medium;

}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
                 <div class="carousel-item active">
                     <img src="img/carleeandiheadertwo.png">
                     <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                         <h1 class="display-2">Michelle Lindemann's Magical Stories</h1>
                         <h3>Bringing your dreams to life!</h3>
                         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">DISCOVER MORE</a>


                     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your styles

```
.display-2{color:#fff;}
```

for white and for black use this

```
.display-2{color:#000;}
```

Comment: The OP has a `.carousel-caption h1` selector, which will match the element, with a rule that includes `color: black !important;` which will color it black...

Answer (score 0):

you have closed header tag before so remove that before the text
`<h1 class="display-2"></h1>Michelle Lindemann's Magical Stories</h1>`